# TFS Workspace.get timing out after an hour, and returning error 500

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using the TFS API (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client`, etc.)

When I am just getting one or two items from the server, it works fine (albeit slowly) - using 
`workspace.Get(getRequests, GetOptions.Overwrite Or GetOptions.GetAll)` 
(where `getRequests` is a `GetRequest()`)

If I am trying to get a large number of items, however, the request times out after an hour with the following error:

> Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     HTTP code 500: Internal Server Error

I don't have access to the TFS server, except via the web front-end (which doesn't let me administer it, for example).

My questions are:

- Where would I look for further logs, to try and troubleshoot this error? (There's nothing in the Windows Event Log)
- What would cause the 1 hour timeout?
- Why is `get`ting so slow in the first place?

--Addendum--

When I replace `workspace.Get(getRequests, GetOptions.Overwrite Or GetOptions.GetAll)` with `For Each getRequest In getRequests
    workspace.Get(getRequest, GetOptions.Overwrite Or GetOptions.GetAll)
Next`

it works fine; but I don't think this is a very efficient method; and I would certainly prefer to get the other method working if I can.

--Addendum II--
The TFS Server event logs have the following events that coincide with the connection failure ({x} = obfuscated information):

Error 3018 in TFS Services -

> TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation
>   component or extension: Date (UTC): 11/10/2016 11:36:31 Machine:
>   {xxxx} Application Domain: {xxxx} Assembly:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727 Service
>   Host: {xxxx} Process Details:   Process Name: w3wp   Process Id: 2600 
>   Thread Id: 8356   Account name: {xxxx}
>
> Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Web Request Details
>       Url: http://{x}/tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx
>   [method: POST]
>       User Agent: Team Foundation (Myapplication.vshost.exe, 11.0.61219.0, Other, SKU:9)
>       Headers: Content-Length=1034987&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip&Accept-Language=en-GB&Expect=100-continue&Host=x%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(Myapplication.vshost.exe%2c+11.0.61219.0%2c+Other%2c+SKU%3a9)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session={Session-GUID}%2c+Get&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fVersionControl%2fClientServices%2f03%2fGet%22
>       Path: /tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx
>       Local Request: False
>       Host Address: {IPADDRESS}
>       User: {MyUSer} [authentication type: NTLM]
>
> Exception Message: Thread was being aborted. (type
>   ThreadAbortException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** ,
>   Int32 )    at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn,
>   IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ObjectBinder`1.TryMoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.CommandGet.ContinueExecution()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.CommandGet.Execute(Workspace
>   workspace, GetRequest[] requests, GetOptions options, Int32
>   maxResults, String[] propertyNameFilters)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.TeamFoundationVersionControlService.Get(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, String workspaceName, String ownerName, GetRequest[]
>   requests, Int32 maxResults, GetOptions getOptions, String[]
>   propertyNameFilters)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.RepositoryExtensions.Get(String
>   workspaceName, String ownerName, GetRequest[] requests, Int32
>   maxResults, Int32 options, String[] propertyNameFilters)

Error - Event 6003 in TFSServices

> TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation
>   component or extension: Date (UTC): 11/10/2016 11:36:31 Machine: {x}
>   Application Domain: {x} Assembly:
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727 Service
>   Host: {x} (TEAM FOUNDATION) Process Details:   Process Name: w3wp
>   Process Id: 2600   Thread Id: 8356   Account name: {x}
>
> Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Web Request Details
>       Url: http://{x}/tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx
>   [method: POST]
>       User Agent: Team Foundation (Myapplication.vshost.exe, 11.0.61219.0, Other, SKU:9)
>       Headers: Content-Length=1034987&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip&Accept-Language=en-GB&Expect=100-continue&Host={x}%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(Myapplication.vshost.exe%2c+11.0.61219.0%2c+Other%2c+SKU%3a9)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session={x}%2c+Get&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fVersionControl%2fClientServices%2f03%2fGet%22
>       Path: /tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx
>       Local Request: False
>       Host Address: {x}
>       User: {x} [authentication type: NTLM]
>
> Exception Message: Request timed out. (type HttpException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:

Warning - ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 - Event 1309

> Event code: 3001  Event message: The request has been aborted.  Event
>   time: 11/10/2016 12:36:31  Event time (UTC): 11/10/2016 11:36:31 
>   Event ID: fb85744596804dcca78d5e54037a5dbb  Event sequence: 3  Event
>   occurrence: 2  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: {x}
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /tfs 
>       Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\ 
>       Machine name: {x}    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 2600 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpException 
>       Exception message: Request timed out.
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: http://{x}/tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx 
> Request path: /tfs/_tfs_resources/VersionControl/v3.0/repository.asmx 
> User host address: {x}
> User: {x}
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: NTLM 
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 11 
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace: 
> Custom event details:
> ```

Comment: Could be many things! Do you have an http proxy on your network? I've seen those cause issues with TFS before, particularly if they are preventing certain file types from being transferred. Do you have the same issue when using Team Explorer to do a get? The IIS logs on the TFS server might provide some insight. Each file request for a file should be a separate http request to the server so you might be able to track down the problem from there

Comment: I have used this before without issues on the same network - it seems to be exactly a 1 hour timeout that is causing problems. Team Explorer doesn't seem to have this issue because it never takes it an hour to get anything. It seems to be failing before it actually gets anything though - adding in the event handler for vcs.Getting doesn't fire in the hour (but with a smaller set of items to get, it fires after about (numberOfGetRequests/87) minutes.

Comment: I have tried replacing `workspace.Get(getRequests)` with `for each getRequest in getRequests workspace.Get(getRequest)` - which works, but obviously causes a lot more load on the TFS Server.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Did you try on another client machine? Did you check the IIS logs and event log on the TFS server?

Comment: I can't check anything on the TFS server - I don't have access to the OS. I am using version 12.0.0.0 of the TFS Client DLLs. I haven't tried on another machine.

Comment: @simonalexander2005, please contact your administrator to check the information on TFS server, maybe the log file can help solve the issue.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT - I have provided the event log traces in the question. It looks like a timeout to me.

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: Could you check which version of TFS are you using? If you are using TFS 2013, try to clean the cache files on TFS machine: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data, and try to run the api on the TFS server to see whether you can reproduce this issue.